# raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause ValueError: Expected singleton:

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo0WU.png)

This my code and i don't know why this error happen.

```
@api.model
def update_prices_in_mitra(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    select_hargamitra = self.env['isd.res.partner.price_list'].search(
        [('partner_id', '=', self.mitra_id.id)])
    cek = []
    # self.task_orderlines = [(5, 0, 0)]
    for cek in select_hargamitra.price_list:
        if (select_hargamitra and (len(select_hargamitra.price_list) > 0)):
            for x in self.task_orderlines:
                if cek.product_id.id == self.product_id.id:
                    x.write({'mitra_price': cek.price_amount,
                             'isd_mitra_status' : True})
```

Comment: File "D:\Yoga\ISD\Odoo14\odoo\http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Expected singleton: isd.res.partner.price_list.detail(60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115)

Comment: The search method may return many records and in this case, `select_hargamitra` should be a recordset. Try to loop over `select_hargamitra` to get the price list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because there might be multiple record in a page i.e. tree view

```
 @api.model
    def update_prices_in_mitra(self):
        for rec in self:
            select_hargamitra = self.env['isd.res.partner.price_list'].search([('partner_id', '=', rec.mitra_id.id)])
            cek = []
            for cek in select_hargamitra.price_list:
                if (select_hargamitra and (len(select_hargamitra.price_list) > 0)):
                    for x in rec.task_orderlines:
                        if cek.product_id.id == rec.product_id.id:
                            x.write({'mitra_price': cek.price_amount,
                                 'isd_mitra_status' : True})
```